# Passing input into powershell script from Ansible

Tags: powershell, ansible

I have a simple powershell script(debug.ps1) which takes user input from read-host and displays it

```
$var = read-host "Enter text"
write-host $var
```

I want to run this from ansible but when I try through stdin, the job executes indefinitely. How do I pass input to read-host from ansible?

```
  tasks:
    - name: Executing script
      win_shell: .\debug.ps1
      
      register: output
      args:
        chdir: C:\Scripts\
        stdin: 'hello'

    - debug: var=output.stdout_lines
```

Comment: Try the [`expect` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html). Note the requirements on the documentation. From a very quick search, it looks like pexpect is available for windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stay away from `Read-Host` as it's intended for interactive logon sessions, not automation.  Convert to a script that accepts parameters and feed a parameter as an argument.  For more advanced cases (which is literally everything other than 'helloworld') check into parameter options.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
  Do this instead
#>
Param(
  [string]$Text
)

$text
```

`Write-Host` used to be really bad because it only wrote to the console, not to one of the out streams (Powershell has 6 last I checked).  However in a recent update, Write-Host now out's to the `Information` stream.  What you need is data out on the `Output` stream for it to be collected properly.

So in short, stay away from `Read-Host` and `Write-Host`, use parameterization and out as object or datatype.  In this case, a `[string]` is a datatype.